# Connect to Hbase instance using nodejs

Tags: node.js, hbase

I am trying to figure out how to connect to Hbase(0.98) using Nodejs. I have tried using hbase-client but that is for hbase 0.94 and below. Can anybody guide me on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple I would use the REST API (or thrift if you are familiar with)